# Difference between commands for removing empty directories

Tags: command-line, rm

What is the difference between `rm --dir <directory>` and `rmdir <directory>` with respect to removing empty directories?

Also, if they are similar, is there any advantage of having an `rmdir` command considering that it is limited only to the removal of empty directories and that the `rm` command can achieve the same functionality (and a lot more) with its numerous options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rmdir` removes empty directories, not files, and not directories unless they are empty.

`rm` will remove files and/or directories, use the `-R` or `-r` flag for directories.

To remove non-empty directories: `rm -rf`

the option `--dir` is the same as `-d` , it will remove empty directories, same as `rmdir`

As far as I know the commands do the same thing and it is user preference which one you use, personally, I use

```
rm -rf
```

I also alias `rm` to `rm -i`

Careful with that command. It is unforgiving if you make a mistake, especially when combined with sudo (which is why I alias it to `rm -i`, the `-f` overrides the `-i`).

I suppose `rmdir` might be safer in that it will not remove a directory unless it is empty first, forcing you to review the contents first.

Comment: +1 for the answer. However, the question is about the difference between `rm --dir` and `rmdir` for removing empty directories. Have edited the question title accordingly.

Comment: Other then the name of the command and options (rm has more options then rmdir) there is no difference.

Comment: I also found the two commands to have the same functionality which made me wonder - "What is the need for `rmdir` when `rm --dir` does the same thing?" The fact that the same author has written both the commands is puzzling.

Comment: I suggest you ask the author, you are sort of moving beyond Ubuntu support and into conjecture. One advantage on Linux, there are often at least 2 ways of accomplishing various tasks.